# Appcelerator android apk using timed function calls crashes below 5.0

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have been using Appcelerator to develop an android app that periodically queries the web server for new entries, downloads the entries and saves them to the local SQLite database and eventually displays them on the HTML webview. The app runs properly on Android 5.0 or above but it crashes on versions 4.4 and below. I am thinking that this could be webkit not being able to handle the `setinterval` functions. Is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your build.gradle file, there is a min-sdk version. 
If the Version is higher, than the SDK of your running android, it won't work.

Comment: I am not sure where to set that through Appcelerator.
I have added this in my tiapp.xml:
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <manifest>
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
     </manifest>
    </android>

Is this what is needed?